# ViewPager present as listView row items are not displayed unless an explicit height is mentioned

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I need to implement an activity where I have a listView and each item of the  listView is a ViewPager which has a swipeable list of images fetched from a server (Similar to the **AirBnB** app, in which on choosing a city you are presented with a list of available homes and each home has a swipeable set of images).

My listView row item is like this (row_item.xml):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/photos_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     </FrameLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

The layout for the ViewPager is like this (view_pager.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I want the images loaded to fill the width of the mobile phone and scale the height appropriately. 
But in row_item.xml unless I specify an explicit height for the FrameLayout, i.e. layout_height= "250dip" or something like that, I cannot see the images loaded. It **appears as if there is no space allocated on the layout for the viewPager unless an explicit height is specified**.

I do not want to specify an explicit height as there will be scaling issues on some devices. An image might have a smaller height than the specified height in dip, and if it tries to scale up to match the specified height the width of the image gets cropped out in the process.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you are controlling the server as well, then you can fix this by sending images of the dimensions which you want

Comment: Also you may want to try it out by keeping scale type of image view to fixtXY. fitXY wont crop the image if the imageview is small - it will accordingly fill up the imageview with the image

Comment: Yeah fitXY works fine! But let's say I have control over the server and I fix image resolutions that should be sent for the different screen densities (hdpi, xhdipi, etc). I can set the height of my root view to some dip, say 250dip and have different copies of the image with heights of appropriate pixels, but what can I do about the width? Different devices have different pixels on the X axis, and I need the image to exactly match the width of the device. Do you have any suggestion?